# Docker image for proxy with GUI to view requests and responses

Tags: docker, proxy

I use Charles webproxy to view the HTTP traffic to and from my application. Would anyone know of a docker image with a proxy with GUI that allows you to see the HTTP requests and responses?

Comment: Are you looking to proxy other containers' traffic or local host traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/), containerized version of mitmproxy: an interactive, SSL/TLS-capable intercepting proxy for HTTP/1, HTTP/2, and WebSockets. It has web interface.

Comment: That's fantastic Jabbson, thanks a lot for pointing me in it's direction!